# Output whole sentence when reversing words in string c++

Tags: c++, string, encryption, reverse

Have to create our own function that receives a sentence/sentences from an input file. It then should reverse the letters of each word individually and leaves all other (non-alphabetic) characters in the plaintext unchanged i.e "The cat sat on the mat!" will become
"ehT tac tas no eht tam!".
So I think I have found a way to reverse words individually but don't know how to find a way to output everything in one sentence. I feel like I would need to somehow use arrays or vectors to help store each word, and then output all the words  together at the end, but I have not been successful.
I also want to find a way for it to know when to stop and to output the blank spaces between words.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void reverse(string input); 

int main(){
    ifstream inData; 
    ofstream outData; 

    string input; 

    inData.open("input.txt"); 
    outData.open("output.txt"); 

    while(getline(inData, input)){
        // cout << input; 
        outData << input; 
    }

   
    reverse(input);

    inData.close(); 
    outData.close(); 
    return 0; 
}

void reverse(string input){
  
    int counter =0;
    while(counter != 14){
    int idx = input.find(" ");
    cout << idx << endl;

    string word = input.substr(0, idx);
    cout << word << endl;
    string x;

    for (int i = idx-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x= word.at(i);
        cout << x; 
    }

    cout << endl;
    input.erase(0,idx+1);

    cout << input << endl;

    cout << endl << "new" << endl;
    
    counter++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: An easy way to get words is to create a `std::istringstream` out of the line from `getline` and break it up with the `>>` operator. `>>` automatically stops on spaces, so all you have to do is watch out for punctuation. `std::istringstream strm(input); std::string word; std::vector<std::string> words; while (strm >> word) { words.push_back(word); }` Giveas a list of words that you can use your own tools on or call `std::reverse(words.begin(), words.end());`

Comment: Unfortunately, @user4581301, this fails to correctly preserve multiple consecutive whitespace. It is unclear whether it is required for the original text string to be untouched, at all, except with all consecutive letters reversed. It's pointless to suggest an approach without having a complete set of specific requirements.

Comment: The string must remain the same, but the letters should be reversed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik want that the reversed words come out in one sentence and not separately.

Comment: Okay , let me try again. How can I join all the reversed words created from each for loop to form one line/one sentence with the same punctuation and spaces as the original sentence. Should I try store them in an array/vector, which seems like the way to go and, how will I go about doing that?

Comment: @Gabriella -- What if the word contains a digit character?  What is `abc1zz` reversed?  Your requirements state non-alphabetic characters must remain in place.  How about `abc!!12345ty`?  If this assignment was given to you by a teacher, then maybe you should get clarification on what to do with these scenarios, because right now, it is not clear.

Comment: There are many possible approaches, there is no single universal way to accomplish this in C++. I would simply use iterators and C++ library algorithms to reverse the letters in each word, in the original string, modifying it. Input string as a parameter? Modify its contents, as described. Then return the string. `input` parameter string contains  "The cat sat on the mat!" on entry to the reversing function, it reverses the letters in the `input` string, directly, making it "ehT tac tas no eht tam!", then returns it. The End.

Comment: @user4581301 So I used stringstream, and there has been improvements. So the for the sentence "The cat sat on the mat!" - I get "ehTtactasnoeht".    Here's the new code for the function.

Comment: (Sorry still new to SO, so don't know how to put the code nicely in comments.)                           `void reverse(string input){
    string reverseString;
    reverseString= " ";
    string outcome;
    int counter =0;
    while(counter != 14){
    int idx = input.find(" ");
    cout << idx << endl;

    string word = input.substr(0, idx);
    cout << word << endl;
    string x;

     
    for (int i = idx-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x= word.at(i);
        cout << x; 
        reverseString.push_back(word[i]);
        
    }`

Comment: `cout << endl;
    input.erase(0,idx+1);

    cout << input << endl;
    cout << endl << "new" << endl;
    counter++; 
    }

    stringstream ss; // creates a string representation
    ss << reverseString; // sends reverse string to string stream
    ss >> outcome ; 
    cout << outcome;
}  `           (end of the code)  

Now my problem is creating a space between each of the words as well as including the last word which seems to be left out. And also need to allow for non-alphabetic characters to remain unchanged. Going to edit these comments to make the code readable

Comment: You can't put code in comments and make it easily legible. This is by design.. What we're supposed to be doing is putting code in the Question or in an Answer. If your code works and solved the problem asked, it's an Answer--a good reason why you want to ask only one, tightly focused question per Question). If not, it's either part of the Question or a new Question. If you narrow the focus of this Question to reversing a single string, you have an answer to that question, post it, and can ask a new question about getting the spaces in there.

Comment: @user4581301 Oh okay, makes sense, thank you so much. So I will need to post a new question about adding spaces separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is code that can output the sentence from the input file, with each word being reversed and all these words then being outputted in one sentence in the order they were in the sentence. There is still some problems to it, like if there is a non-alphabetic character in the word, at the front or somewhere before the end, that character will be pushed to the back of the word, so this needs to be improved on. Feel free to nicely add constructively criticism if have any. However, think this still provides for the original question. Thank you all for the help.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std; 

void reverse(string input); 

int main(){
    ifstream inData; 
    ofstream outData; 

    string input; 

    inData.open("input.txt"); 
    outData.open("output.txt"); 

    while(getline(inData, input)){          //get sentence from input line
        reverse(input);                     //Reverse the sentence
        cout << endl;                       //end line for next sentence
    }

    inData.close(); 
    outData.close(); 
    return 0; 
}

void reverse(string input){
    string nonAlpha = "";
    bool end = false;
    bool nonLetter = true;

    while(end != true){         
    int idx = input.find(" ");                       //Finds index of blank space
    int lastIdx = input.size();                      //Finds the last index

    if(idx <= 0){                                    //If it is the last index, then that becomes idx
        idx = lastIdx;
        end = true;
    }

    string word = input.substr(0, idx);               //Word usually starts from index 0, until the blank space
    string x;

     
    for (int i = idx-1; i >= 0; i--){                  //Then outputs each letter according to the index of the word 
                                                      // but starts from last index and decrements thereby reversing the word
        if((isalpha(word.at(i))==false)){               //If that index is not a letter then it is stored and will be outputted after word 
           nonAlpha.push_back(word[i]);                 //However this can be a problem for non-letter if not at end of word
           nonLetter = true; 
        }
        else{
        x= word.at(i);
        cout << x;                                      //Prints the letter
        }
        
    }
    
    if(nonLetter == true){
    cout << nonAlpha;                                   //Prints the non-letter
    nonAlpha.erase();                                   //Erases whatever is inside for future non-letters
    nonLetter = false;                                  //Makes it false and will be used agaian when there is another non-letter
    }
    
    cout << " ";                                        //Space between words
    input.erase(0,idx+1);                               //Erases word when finished reversing and outputting it so can start next word

    }

}
```